# Identify $\int_{0}^t \text{sign}(X_t) dX_t$ when $X_t = a + b t + W_t$.

Tags: integration, normal-distribution, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

If $W_t$ is a standard Brownian motion, I know that $$\int_0^t \operatorname{sign}(W_s) \, {\rm d}W_s$$ is also a standard Brownian motion, where $\operatorname{sign}(x) = \begin{cases} +1 &\text{if } x \geq 0\\ -1 &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

Thanks to Lévy's theorem, when $X_t = a + b t + W_t$, we know that

$$Z_t = \frac1{b} \int_0^t \text{sign}(X_s) \, {\rm d}X_s$$

is  a Brownian motion. I wonder if we can get a simple formula for it expected value. In others words, because of the martingale property of the stochastic integral, I would like to compute

$$ \mathbb{E} \left(\int_0^t \operatorname{sign}(X_s) \,{\rm d}s \right) $$

I get expressions involving

$$\Phi(x) = \int_{x}^{\infty} e^{-u^2/2} \frac{du}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}$$

but no simple formula.

Comment: I do not think that $Z_t$ is a BM simply because $X_t$ is not a martingale and $Z_t$ is not a martingale. Further hint: use Girsanov's theorem to transform $X_t$ into a BM.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I had never used Girsanov theorem.